# unique identifier for each task in each project but not across the all projects( multitenant issue)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uniqueidentifier, multi-tenant

I am working on rails 4 application where I have many projects and each project has many tasks.

My problem is I want to uniquely identify each task in a project like want to give first two character and then task id so its became xy-1, xy-2 but as all task stored in task table for the second project it start from ab-3 since id of that task is 3.

What I want is it should start from ab-1 since it is first task for that project.

There should not be a problem of deletion also since task can be deleted.

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you can do is to create some 'increment' field in project model and set to be type integer. For example, you have project xy and increment field set to 0 (let's say 0 is default). When you want to create task for that project, you just read increment field (this case 0), add its 1 (0+1), and then again save project. That value you can use for task id and make something: xy-1. It should look like:

```
project = Project.find(10)
curr_inc = project.increment
curr_inc += 1
project.increment = curr_inc
project.save
task_id = "#{project.code}-#{curr_inc}"
```